# Клик мимо грида в ExtJS

Tags: extjs

Здравствуйте. Есть грид с записями, а справа панель подробного просмотра этой записи. Заказчик хочет, чтоб при клике мимо записи выделенная запись сбрасывалась. Как зачастую в ОС - клик мимо снимает выделенный текущий элемент.
Как отловить такое событие? Пока ничего путного не приходит в голову - элементов на странице много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда занимался разработкой событий на канвасе, делал так:
Создавал прозрачный слой поверх элемента такого же размера и характеристик и отлавливал его клики по событиям. Помогало когда элемент составной, а события нужны для всего "вида".
В вашем случае можно сделать следующим образом:
Создать слой перехватчик и когда возникает событие фокуса таблицы отображать его по иерархии сразу за таблицей, соответственно клик по нему будет делать то что вам нужно. По принципу всплывающих окон с затемнением, только без затемнения.
Не решение, просто идея.